# Approximate x*(a/b)^(c/d) using integer arithmetic only (assembler)

Tags: approximation, arithmetic, integers, assembly

0 < x,a,b,c,d < M are all positive integers (uint64).
also, a<b if that helps.

we have assembler (integer only) operations available (e.g. division only yields integers).

we want to approximate: x*(a/b)^(c/d)

how to do this in the simplest way?

thx

edit: added x

Comment: What's the motivation for assuming you can only use assembly language (and not, e.g., standard libraries)?  You can, of course, re-implement any existing library, but why would you want to?  e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation

Comment: I am coding this in assembly. In TEAL, to be specific.

Comment: What if the result is not integer ? The range of (a/b)^(c/d) can by very far exceed the range of uint64.

Comment: Do you have serious reasons to use such fractions ? If this is to solve number theoretic problems, the range of uint64 seems so tiny; and if this is to solve numerical problems, rationals are probably quite inappropriate. Just for fun ?

Comment: While I think it much more likely that `^` is to denote exponentiation (see post editor help about MathJax) rather than *exclusive or*: Is it *Integer approximation of the rational number $\frac a b$ to the rational number $\frac c d$th power* , or *integer approximation of (the integer approximation of $\frac a b$ to the integer approximation of $\frac c d$)th power* ?

Comment: "Coding in TEAL" is not computer science.

Comment: it is exponentiation: a/b to the power of c/d.

Comment: the result might not be an integer, true - i should add, actually the calc is: x*(a/b)^(c/d) - so after multiplying with another integer x, we get something close to an integer

Comment: ""Coding in TEAL" is not computer science" - it is a CS question how such a calculation could be done in an assembler, i.e. integer arithmetic only

Comment: it is not entirely for fun - i am coding it for a virtual machine that runs assembly only. the calc is required for  something called an LP (liquidity pool)

Comment: It is very likely that the input values for which you need to compute the powers correspond to very limited ranges. You must tell us. The "simplest way" is probably by tabulating.

Comment: IMO, it is completely inappropriate to perform this computation from inside this TEAL machine.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to implement exponentiation is using logarithm and exponentiation.  In particular,

$$u^v = e^{v \log u}.$$

So, you need algorithms for multiplication, division, exponentiation, and logarithm.  Multiplication and division are documented well in many standard places.  Some algorithms for division can be found on Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Calculation.  A standard way to compute $e^x$ is using the Taylor series expansion of that function.

See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/83785/19041, https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10425/19041.